# Enable/Disable iPad configuration for multiple App flavour (Production/UAT)

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, ipad

I have a Flutter App where i need to enable the iPad compatibility only in specific flavour for example Development.

We know that we can check the iPad option in supported destination. But how can this be achieved if we want to enable it on the basis of flavours ?

Not able to find any option for this.